# Triangulation Question

Tags: trigonometry, triangulation

I am working my way through a book called *Trigonometry: A Complete Introduction*.

I am stuck on one of the triangulation questions and was wondering of someone could help. The answer is 2.23 km but i don't get anywhere near that answer.

Can someone help?

[image: Excercise 6.3 Q8]

[working out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoxMf.png)

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Perhaps the following figure will help:

[image]

Consider that

$$x+y=m\cot(\alpha)+m\cot(\beta)=5.$$

Now, you have $m$. Then $m'$. Then $h$.

Comment: Can you work it out with the values in the question? I am having trouble with this. I have used the law of sines and your method but do not get the right answer. I put my attempt in a picture in the body of my question. Its just the first part, working m out. But i think it is wrong.